# MMS from app and assigning to contact?

Tags: ios, uiimage, mms

I have an app that allows me to make changes to a given image and I would like to:

1) Be able to send that image as an MMS/iMessage. I have not found anything specific in the Apple documentation in this regard. Is it even possible?

2) Assign that image to a contact in the address book. Is there something in the SDK that would allow me to do so? Like, when the user wants to add an image to the contact, display the contact list and just allow them to add the image as they would from the Photos app.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) As of iOS 5 there is no way to pre-populate anything other than the recipients and message body text for a a message.

2) You can use [ABPeoplePickerNavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007078) to present a view like the default iOS Address Book UI so the user can select a contact. This controller will return to you the selected contact record which you can use to programmatically set change that contact's photo.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it's possible to set a wallpaper from within an app through the SDK?